# refactor method with two foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, refactoring

I run into refactoring problem. I have many similar methods, but i cannot find way to extract one line form them and make another private method.

```
private function constructRules($rules, \Languages $langs) {
    foreach ($rules as $fieldType => $rule) {
        foreach ($langs->all() as $lang) {
           //line below changes
            $langRules[$fieldType . '[' . $lang->lang . ']'] = $rule; 
        }       
    }

    return $langRules;
}
```

I have these foreach loops in 4 different places. If i extact foreach loops and return array, I still need to make one foreach loop in method, to fill $langRules in this example. Maybe there are simple way to do it, but I am not able to see it...

Comment: This question is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's unclear what your method does, but do you really need all languages, every time? If you only need one it's obvious what you could do.

Comment: This isn't a code review question, as they're not asking for the code to be reviewed. They're asking for how to refactor it for portability, which is a different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not just a matter of factoring out the "task" part of that code into a callback?

```
private function constructRulesUsingCallBack($rules, \Languages $langs, $task) {
    $langRules = [];
    foreach ($rules as $fieldType => $rule) {
        foreach ($langs->all() as $lang) {
           $task($langRules, $fieldType, $lang, $rule);
        }       
    }

    return $langRules;
}

$langRules = constructRulesUsingCallBack($rules, $langs, function (&$langRules, $fieldType, $lang, $rule) {
    $langRules[$fieldType . '[' . $lang->lang . ']'] = $rule; 
});
```

I'm not so au fait with PHP, and I am not happy with the amount of boilerplate I need in the inline function expression to work, but PHP doesn't seem to implement closure very well (that I could work out, anyhow).

However you can leave the `constructRulesUsingCallBack()` function as is to just handle the looping now, and simply pass a different implementation of the callback body to it each time you need to process something within those loops.

That *seems* to fulfil what you need it to, based on your example. If not, pls clarify and I might be able to augment this to cover your needs.